# Uri image drawing

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to drawItem from uri like: "http://profile/imgpath/0234245222.jpg", but I got error with uri not supported.

I used to drawItem image as byte, I never draw from uri.

help me please!

```
    private int mouseIndex = -1;

    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index == -1) return;
        Image avatarContact = null;
        Mycontact contact = (Mycontact)listBox1.Items[e.Index];

        Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
        if (e.Index > -1)
        {
            // Drawing the frame
            if (e.Index == mouseIndex)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.HotTrack, e.Bounds);
                textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
                    textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
                }else{
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                }
                // Drawing the Avatar Image
                if (contact.P_AVATAR_IMAGE != null)
                {
                    // displaying avatar picture
                    // if byte image
                    //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(contact.P_AVATAR_IMAGE);
                    //avatarContact = Image.FromStream(stream );


                }
                else
                {
                    // if the contact has no avatar image, we can use a default one
                    if (contact.P_GENDER == "male") avatarContact = defaultMaleAvatar;
                    if (contact.P_GENDER == "female") avatarContact = defaultFemaleAvatar;
                }
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(avatarContact, e.Bounds.Left -2, e.Bounds.Top - 2, 50,40);

            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: What is `profile` in the url? Is that really your domain?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [MSDN Forum Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/1817a17b-36ae-4d8f-be94-e6afc1361955), they suggest doing something like this.

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("http://profile/imgpath/0234245222.jpg");
 WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
 Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
 Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: My C# not unknown WebRequest!, need me to add which referent?